# How to add notification observer for UIDocument?

Tags: swift, notifications

```
private var documentObserver: NSObjectProtocol?

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

documentObserver  = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: Notification.Name.UIDocumentStateChangedNotification ,
            object: document,
            queue: OperationQueue.main,
            using: { notification in
                print("docuemntState Changed to \(self.document!.documentState)")
            }
        )
```

}

I'm trying to do like that but Xcode shows me an error :

> Type 'Notification.Name' (aka 'NSNotification.Name') has no member
>   'UIDocumentStateChangedNotification '

Answer (score 2):

Notification name that you're looking for is static constant of `UIDocument`

```
UIDocument.stateChangedNotification
```

Comment: Yes, that is the correct fix for EmojiArt project in CS193P Developing Apps for iOS
Stanford University. School of Engineering. Professor Paul Hegarty. September 25, 2017 - November 29, 2017